# WebGoat 8: JWT Tokens Lesson 5 using hashcat to crack signature

Tags: hash, webgoat

I cracked the hash, and I got this:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJXZWJHb2F0IFRva2VuIEJ1aWxkZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE1MjQyMTA5MDQsImV4cCI6MTYxODkwNTMwNCwiYXVkIjoid2ViZ29hdC5vcmciLCJzdWIiOiJ0b21Ad2ViZ29hdC5jb20iLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IlRvbSIsIkVtYWlsIjoidG9tQHdlYmdvYXQuY29tIiwiUm9sZSI6WyJNYW5hZ2VyIiwiUHJvamVjdCBBZG1pbmlzdHJhdG9yIl19.vPe-qQPOt78zK8wrbN1TjNJj3LeX9Qbch6oo23RUJgM:victory
```

Is 'victory' the secret key? What do I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a JWT token. I can tell by the three base 64 encoded parts separated by dots. You can decode the token easily on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/).

To prevent people from changing the token, it is cryptographically signed using a secret key. You cracked the secret key, making it possible to alter the JWT token or create a new JWT token. What the impact of this is depends on the information stored in the JWT token, but typically it makes it possible to create a session token for another user.